# Swift: Alamofire POST Request with JSON Object as body

Tags: json, swift, post, alamofire

I have this request:

```
curl -X "POST" "myURL" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'User-Agent: myAgent)' \
-H 'Accept-Language: it-IT' \
-d $'{ "Summary": { "Discount": 1.099, "TotalAmount": 9.891, "SubtotalAmount": 10.99 }, "Token": "token", "InstantDiscountId": "id" }'
```

but I don't know how to set the body with that JSON object. With Alamofire I always used [String:Any] as parameters in the request but that's not the case.

Comment: Just set the request's encoding to `JSONEncoding.default`

Comment: @ZonilyJame how would you create the [String:Any] object for that JSON? I already tried...

Comment: Ok it was just a problem of how I created parameters object... thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to simply set the encoding to `JSONEncoding.default`

Here's how it would look like as code

```
let request = Alamofire.request(
    myUrl,
    method: .post,
    parameters: [
        "Summary": [
            "Discount": 1.099,
            "TotalAmount": 9.891,
            "SubtotalAmount": 10.99
        ],
        "Token": "token",
        "InstantDiscountId": "id"
    ],
    encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
    headers: [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "myAgent",
        "Accept-Language": "it-IT"
    ]
)
```